# how create an animation

Tags: python, animation

i'm a beginner in python, i really don't know how create an animation. I have different plots and i want to create a short video that concatenate these plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[2,1,9],[2,2,0]]
a=pd.DataFrame(data)
a.columns=['x','y','value']

data2=[[1,1,5],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,2,3]]
b=pd.DataFrame(data2)
b.columns=['x','y','value']

data3=[[1,1,15],[1,2,7],[2,1,4],[2,2,8]]
c=pd.DataFrame(data3)
c.columns=['x','y','value']

final=[a,b,c]

for i in range(0,len(final)):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.scatter(final[i]['x'],final[i]['y'],c=final[i]['value'],vmin=0, vmax=15,)
    plt.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python isn't really the way to go for creating a video.**

If you want to present your graph(s) in video format, screenshot them using Windows Button + Print Screen (PrtSc) on your keyboard. This will save a screenshot to your pictures folder. Then, use a video editor, such as [Vegas](https://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/gb/) or free options like [WeVideo](https://www.wevideo.com/) to put the screenshots into a video.

You can also use presentation software, like [Prezi](https://prezi.com/), for a more engaging experience.